# What does `NUMERIC maxsize 256` mean in mysql?

Tags: mysql, numeric

Here is a data fields definition:

| Field Name | Field Description | Field Type (format) | Max Size | May be NULL | Key |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| tag | The unique identifier (name) for a tag in a specific taxonomy release. | ALPHANUMERIC | 256 | No | * |
| version | For a standard tag, an identifier for the taxonomy; otherwise the accession number where the tag was defined. | ALPHANUMERIC | 20 | No | * |
| ddate | The end date for the data value, rounded to the nearest month end. | DATE (yyyymmdd) | 8 | No | * |
| qtrs | The count of the number of quarters represented by the data value, rounded to the nearest whole number. “0” indicates it is a point-in-time value. | NUMERIC | 8 | No | * |
| uom | The unit of measure for the value. | ALPHANUMERIC | 20 | No | * |
| coreg | If specified, indicates a specific co-registrant, the parent company, or other entity (e.g., guarantor). NULL indicates the consolidated entity. | NUMERIC | 256 | Yes | * |
| value | The value. This is not scaled, it is as found in the Interactive Data file, but is limited to four digits to the right of the decimal point. | NUMERIC(28,4) | 16 | Yes |  |
| footnote | The text of any superscripted footnotes on the value, as shown on the statement page, truncated to 512 characters, or if there is no footnote, then this field will be blank. | ALPHANUMERIC | 512 | Yes |  |

The field definition is  `SEC U.S. Securities and Exchange Commission`'s official material:

[sec official material](http://%20https://www.sec.gov/data/financial-statements/aqfs.pdf)

For `coreg` ,it's field type is numeric ,max size 256 ,how to write the create statement?

```
CREATE TABLE `num` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `tag` VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
    `version` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    `ddate` DATE NOT NULL,
    `qtrs` DECIMAL(8) NOT NULL,
    `uom` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    `coreg` ?,
    `value` DECIMAL(28,4),
    `footnote` VARCHAR(512),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

To write the field definiton as below?

```
`coreg` NUMERIC(256)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL the maximum number of digits for `decimal` (`numeric`) type is 65.

So, you can't technically define a column as `NUMERIC(256)`.

[11.1.3 Fixed-Point Types (Exact Value) - DECIMAL, NUMERIC](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fixed-point-types.html)

> The maximum number of digits for DECIMAL is 65

---

It doesn't really make sense to me to have the "the parent company, or other entity (e.g., guarantor)" defined as a number, even as a really long number.

Maybe there is a typo and really it should read "ALPHANUMERIC", i.e. a text value.

If this value will never be interpreted as a number and there will never be attempts to make some calculations with this number (as the field description implies), then it should be stored as a text (`varchar(256)`); maybe with some extra checks that you can store only digits 0-9 and not any symbol there.

Comment: It is a typo after checking content in `num.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

It probably means it's just a long sequence of digits. You would typically store it as a `NUMERIC` but a size of 256 digits is beyond MySQL's limit for numeric types. You can store it, however, as a `VARCHAR(256)` and add a `CHECK` constraint on it.

**Note**: `CHECK` constraints are enforced only in MySQL 8.0 (8.0.3?) and newer.

For example:

```
create table t (
  coreg varchar(256) check (coreg regexp '^[0-9]+$')
);

insert into t (coreg) values ('123');
insert into t (coreg) values ('x456'); -- fails
insert into t (coreg) values ('7y89'); -- fails
insert into t (coreg) values ('012z'); -- fails
insert into t (coreg) values ('345 '); -- fails
```

See running example in [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d2d3745fa7dc3f61ff77e8ef10e9d176).